# Finding the coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: interpolation

There is a polynomial $f(x,y) = \sin(\theta) x^2 + \cos(\theta)y^3 + x^2+ x^3y^2 +5$, where $\theta= g(x,y)$. Can we find the coefficients of $f(x,y)$ using any interpolation method?

Comment: $f$ is not a polynomial if $\theta$ depends on $x,y$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You problem is too poorly defined to admit an answer. Can you be more specific about what you are wanting? Do you want to break down the $xy$ plane into squares and interpolate between values at the corner, maybe?